# Apply directive to a dynamically created DOMs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on an AngularJS app and I am using the following directive

```
app.directive('w34Lang', function () {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    template : "<select ng-model='language'><option selected disabled value=''>Language</option></select>",
    link: function (scope, elem) {
        scope.isolateScope = true;
      var lang=   angular.element( elem.find('select')[0]);
        var langs = ["arabic" ,"english","Portugal"]
        for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; i++) {
            lang.append('<option value="'+langs[i]+'">'+langs[i]+'<otion>');

        }


        }
    }

})
```

in the HTML I am using this directive with no problems, the issue is when I am adding a dynamically created DOM element with the same directive . it just created in the HTML but the directive not applied to it.

Is there anyway to apply directives to dynamically created DOMs ?

Comment: Depending on how you are creating the new elements you may need to compile the content or fire off a $digest cycle.

Answer (score 2):

Never heard of `exec`, or been able to find any documentation on it. What is that?

Anyway, in your `link` function, you need to compile your dynamically generated DOM. Like this:

```
app.directive('w34Lang', function () {
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        template : "<select ng-model='language'><option selected disabled value=''>Language</option></select>",
        scope: {},
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            var langs = ["arabic", "english", "Portugal"];

            for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; i++) {
                var template = '<option value="' + langs[i] + '">' + langs[i] + '</option>';

                elem.append(angular.element(template));
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: the 'exec' is an alternative to link, anyway I have tried your solution but with no luck the new element created  is empty even the main template in the directive which is the select tag not exists .